# insert an ObjectId in another user - Parse and Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, parse-platform, insert

I am currently trying to save an objectId in another user's array. unfortunately, I am getting an error. here is what I tried :

```
let name = (PFUser.currentUser()!["FirstName"] as! String) + " " + (PFUser.currentUser()!["LastName"] as! String)

let News = News(title: "\(name) accepted your ...", user: PFUser.currentUser()!)

News.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if (success){

        let user = self.interest.user as! User
        user.joinNews(News.objectId!)

    } else {
        print("--------")
    }
})
```

And here is the func joinNews I created for this :

```
public func joinNews(newsId: String) {
    newsIds.insert(newsId, atIndex: 0)

    saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for you help !

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: oh yeah sorry I forgot that ... my bad ... here it is : "Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User object has a special security : it can only be updated by the user itself, that's why you get the error "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp"

If you want an action of the current user to modify another user object, you need to use a cloud code function, and use the Parse master key, to override this security.

This would look like :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addNewsToUser", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.id = request.params.userId;
  user.fetch().then(function(object) {
    // modify the user here

    return user.save();
  }).then(function() {
    response.success(user);
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks :) do you know another way to make something that resemble a news feed ? my goal is to create a Post with a like button and each time this button is pressed, the user that created the post knows someone liked it. do you have any idea on how to do that ?